# convert char[] to BigDecimal [], general concept

Tags: java

I have a task. I just wanted to discuss the main concept of it.:

1. User enter from keyboard items, for example `"ABCD"`
2. each item has predefined price, like `A=$1.25`
3. i need to return summ of `"ABCD"` using `BigDecimal` API.

My idea is (in few words):

1. `char[] items = bufferRead.readLine().toCharArray(); // using BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))`
2. convert `char[]` items to `BigDecimal[]`
3. count summ of `BigDecimal`

Does it sound good ?

Please do not provide a code :) I just want to create clean, well-factored, OO code :) 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds good in general, but in 2. you should do a mapping from char to BigDecimal

Comment: Sounds fantastic, however SO isn't a discussion board. Write some code up and if you get stuck we will be happy to help.

Comment: @ns47731 - I disagree. The OP is asking whether the design/approach is correct . We could suggest a better approach (like using a Map or creating an object etc.) I think its a valid question on SOF.

Comment: My suggestion - just start writing some code. Perhaps at some point you'll get to a "Oh wait, this won't work at all" point, but then you'll know, first-hand, why it won't work, and you'll certainly remember it far better than you would from just reading someone's answer on [so]. Then you'll fix it up and hopefully get some working code eventually. This should also be a much more rewarding experience than just asking someone whether it's right. After you've written the code, you could even post it on [codereview.se], so you could get a few suggestions about possible improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `charValueMap` of type `Map<Character, BigDecimal>` to map 'A' with 1.25, 'B' with otherValue and so on.

Then read `input` from user like following:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Sytem.in);
System.out.println("Enter input: ");
String input = scanner.nextLine();
scanner.close();
```

Then use this `input` and calculate the `sum` like following:

```
BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for(char c : input.toCharArray())
{
  sum = sum.add(charValueMap.get(c));
}

System.out.println(sum.toString());
```

The above snippet assumes that you are entering valid input. If the mapping of any particular character is not found in the `charValueMap`, it will throw an error, so don't forget to add some defensive code prior to calculating the `sum`.

Comment: @WhoAmI Ironic considering OP asked to not provide code. But good code none the less.

Comment: answer is quite good and compact but I feel this is homework of OP which you have just done :)

Comment: @ns47731 - I agree :). An algorithm would have been sufficient.

Comment: No, he/she hasn't done the homework.  There's not really any mention of how to create or populate the map.  So all that he/she has done is answer the question.  This is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible prototype

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   char input[] = getUserInput();
   Map<Character, Double> items = processUserInput(input);
   BigDecimal result = getResult(items);
}

/**
 * Get user input from keyboard.
 */
private static char[] getUserInput() {
   // do something
   return null;
}

/**
 * Associate each item with its price.
 */
private static Map<Character, Double> processUserInput(char[] input) {
   // do something
   return null;
}

/**
 * Count summ of each item.
 */
private static BigDecimal getResult(Map<Character, Double> items) {
   // do something;
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Hello,Thank you ALL for your your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    // predefined list...
    BigDecimal predefinedValues[] = { BigDecimal.valueOf(1.25), BigDecimal.valueOf(2.50), BigDecimal.valueOf(0.95) };
    // the variable use to calculate the total
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    // Input from the user
    char items[] = bufferRead.readLine().toCharArray();
    // basic loop to calculate the total and catch "bad" inputs.
    for ( char item: items )
    {
        int index = (item - 'A'); // this assumes ALL characters are uppercase!
        if ( index >= 0 && index < predefinedValues.length )
            total.add(predefinedValues[index]);
        else
            System.err.println("Bad input encountered: " + item);
    }
```